# How to delete specific row in MySQL using forms with same names in php?

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have a series of articles on my webpage. Each of these has a delete form with the same name ("article"). All of my POSTs are done through ajax and work fine! The one problem I have now is that only the last article gets deleted. The hidden input has a value of the row# in the database This is the output I get:

```
  'deletearticle' => 'article=31&article=27&article=21',
```

Here's my AJAX:

```
    $('.deleteForm').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'functions/check.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            deletearticle: $('.deleteForm').serialize()
        },
        success: function(data){
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

And here's my delete

```
    if (isset($_POST['deletearticle'])) {
    parse_str($_POST['deletearticle'], $deletearticle);
    $id = $deletearticle['article'];

    try {
        $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("DELETE FROM articles WHERE id = ".$id." ");
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Fail: ".$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

**EDIT** I do know about name=XXX[]. It just doesn't tell me which one in the array was picked by the user to delete.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use the `article[]` syntax as the form element name.

Then PHP automatically converts it to an array of paramaters.

Of course you need then to change your SQL to something like

```
WHERE articleId IN( ' . $articleIds . ' )
```

But read first about proper sql escaping http://php.net/manual/de/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: I've tried using article[] but it's no good if I just get an array with a bunch of IDs. I need to know which one the user picked to delete. 

Also, if you're referring to using "$id" in the sql, I know I should use ":id" and bind it before execution. This is just for testing purposes.